# How to post List<Data> using retrofit in android

Tags: android, list, post, retrofit

Here is my api's body

```
    [{  "imageBitmap":"demo",
        "driver":"demo",
        "dateTimeIn":"demo",
        "dateTimeOut":"demo",
        "location":"demo"},
{
    "imageBitmap":"demo",
        "driver":"demo",
        "dateTimeIn":"demo",
        "dateTimeOut":"demo",
        "location":"demo"}]
```

How do i post data by this method using retrofit in android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1: Create a model class contains those JSON Objects

Step 2: Add function in `APIService` class (In your service class) as below shown:

```
@POST("url/api_path")
Call<ResponseBody> postData(@Body List<ModelClass> object);
```

Step 3: Create a `List<ModelClass> listObject`, and add `ModelClass`'s objects to `listObject`.

Step 4: Call function with `listObject` as parameter . i.e, `postData(listObject);`

Hope this help you!